# Open recent directories like Ido opens files

Tags: dired, ido, recentf

When I want to open a recent file, I use `ido-find-find` (`C-x C-f`) or `ido-switch-buffer` (`C-x b`) and type a few characters and Ido automatically finds the right file among the recent files I have visited.

I would like to have something similar for directories. For example, with `ido-dired`, Ido suggests the current directory and I have to navigate my filesystem to reach the one I have in mind. For example, to reach `~/some/sub/directory/containing/the/RightDirectory/`, I have to type in the first letters of all the parent directories (and remember them) to reach `RightDirectory/`. I find that cumbersome.

Is there a way to get an interface similar to `ido-find-file` to reach a recent directory?

Note: I am open to any other suggestion of workflow to reach a recent (or any) directory quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Something quick. Far from perfection, but it's a start. (You might want to add some cache mechanism since it's rather slow)

```lisp
(defun find-recent-dirs (dir)
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Recent dirs: "
                          (-filter (lambda (p) (and (not (file-remote-p p))
                                               (f-directory? p)))
                                   (-uniq (-map #'f-dirname recentf-list)))))))
  (find-file dir))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am open to any other suggestion of workflow to reach a recent (or any) directory quickly.

[Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) lets you open a Dired buffer that shows recently used directories (commands `diredp-dired-recent-dirs` and `diredp-dired-recent-dirs-other-window`, bound globally to **`C-x D r`** and **`C-x 4 D r`**).

This is similar to the commands showing recent *files* (`C-x D R` and `C-x 4 D R`).

`C-h C-x D r` says:

> Open Dired in `BUFFER`, showing recently visited directories.
>
> Like `diredp-dired-recent-files`, but limited to recent directories.
> *A directory is recent if any of its files is recent.*

The more extensive doc string for `C-x D R` (recent files) says this.  It all applies also to the recent-directories commands.

> `diredp-dired-recent-files` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `dired+.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x D R`.
>
> `(diredp-dired-recent-files BUFFER &optional ARG FILES)`
>
> Open Dired in `BUFFER`, showing recently visited files and directories.
>
> You are prompted for `BUFFER` (default: `Recently Visited Files`).
>
> With a ***numeric** prefix arg* you can enter names of recent files to
> *include or exclude*.
>
> *No prefix arg or a **plain** prefix arg* (`C-u`, `C-u C-u`, etc.) means
> list *all* of the recently used files.
>
> With a prefix arg:
>
> - If 0, `-`, or plain (`C-u`) then you are prompted for *the `ls` switches* to use.
> - If not plain (`C-u`) then:
>
>   - If >= 0 then the *files to include* are read, one by one.
>   - If  < 0 then the *files to exclude* are read, one by one.
>
> When entering files to include or exclude, use `C-g` to end.
>
> The file listing is *sorted by option
> `diredp-default-sort-arbitrary-function`*, if non-`nil`.  If `nil` (the
> default) then the listing is in reverse chronological order of opening
> or writing files you access.
>
> Use `g` to *revert* the buffer, as usual.  If you use it without a
> prefix arg then the same files are relisted.  A *prefix arg* is handled
> as for `C-x D R` itself.
>
> When called from Lisp:
>
> - `ARG` corresponds to the raw prefix arg.
> - `FILES` is passed to `diredp--dired-recent-files-1`.  It is used only
>   when the command is used as part of the `revert-buffer-function`.

You can even *sort* such Dired buffers, using **`C-M-L`** (aka `C-M-S-l`).